# Vue.JS passing computed values from root to child component using props

Tags: jquery, dom, vue.js, components

So I have a demo app in which I am generating a random number in via computed property in root and passing that computed value to child component using props.

I am not able to figure out correct way to update value in child component whenever I generate random value on click.

Also, jquery dom selection is weird it sometime gives me undefined and sometime it works and highlight the cell.

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/xblack/pen/RvZBBZ)

```
Vue.component('grid',{
  template:'#grid',
  props:['randval'],
  data:function(){
    return{
      title:"items",
      items:["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
    }
  },
  computed:{
    getValues:function(){ 
      $('.cells').removeClass('highlight');
      $('#cell_'+this.randval).addClass('highlight');
      console.log($('#cell_').text(), this.$refs.cell_1); // for example this return undefined sometime and works other times
      return this.randval;
    }
  } 
});

let app = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    val:0
  },
  methods:{
    randFun:function(){ 
      this.val = parseInt(Math.random()*10);
    }
  },
  computed:{
    watchVal:function(){ 
      return (this.val<9)?this.val:0;
    }  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`v-bind:class`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax)

And also you can `watch` a props value.

```js
computed: {
  getValues:function(){
    // ...
  }
},
watch: {
  randval(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log('newVal: ', newVal);
    console.log('oldVal: ', oldVal);
  }
}
```

```html
<li v-for="item, i in items" class="cells"
  :class="{ highlight: (i === randval) }">
```

[**Check in Codepen**](https://codepen.io/sajibcse68/pen/XOaQzp)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply and I know this approach but I would want to know how can it be done using my approach. This is a demo code which obviously the part of a bigger snippet which I can't share here so I am asking if it can be done be done with my approach?

Comment: so, what is the exact approach you want?

Comment: Do you want to use jQuery/getValues()/else? FYI: it is strictly prohibited to change HTML directly using jQuery or else, if so then Vue / virtual-dom will not work perfectly!

Comment: I have mentioned two problems, one is where I wanted to send computed values to child component via props but also update the values everytime I compute value from root. What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Another one is to manipulate DOM if not JQuery then what would be the correct way?

Comment: First one, you are already passing props form parent to child by `<grid v-bind:randval="watchVal"></grid>` . Second: you need to use various vue directives (v-bind, js codes, etc) in template to manipulate DOM

Comment: Yes, you are correct but randval is not computing when updated from root. You can try console logging inside getValue() and check. It is not even triggering.

Comment: I think it's always updating... try replacing `{{ item }}` to `{{item}} - {{ randval }}` then click the button

Comment: yes, but why computed getvalue() is not getting triggered? It should compute everytime it see any changes in the randval, right?

Comment: But if I call {{getValue}} instead of {{randval}} then I can see console getting logged.

Comment: you can watch the `randval`, it will be triggered when the props chages

Comment: Even, I tried that but as Vue documentation suggesting to avoid using watcher instead  of computed property so I wanted to make it work but I guese that's not possible. Can you try answering me second part where I asked how to access element with id and toggele class ?

Comment: Why you don't binding the `:class`? it's easy and recommended instead changing DOM directly

Comment: so basically I am calculating the tiled on the fly with rows and column number like (r=3,c=2) index=r+c*2 $('#cel_'+index).addClass('highlight); and want to remove same class from rest of the cell.

Comment: you can implement the logic in template and set the `highlight` class dynamically.. can you explain the logic of `highlight` class details depending on rows/col?

Answer (score 0):

Update the component like this and it seems like that it is the only way to update the props and watch them -

```
Vue.component('grid',{
  template:'#grid',
  props:['randval'],
  data:function(){
    return{
      title:"items",
      items:["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"],
      final:0
    }
  },
  watch: {
    randval:function(){   
      this.final = this.randval;
      console.log('watching randvals-->',this.randval);  
    }
  }, 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger prop. Upon updating trigger prop, we can generate new Random Value from random component.

```js
Vue.component('grid',{
  template:'#grid',
  props:['randval'],
  data:function(){
    return{
      title:"items",
      items:["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
    }
  } 
});
Vue.component('random', {
  props: [
    'trigger',
    'min',
    'max'
  ],
    computed: {
    random() {
      this.trigger;
 return  Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.max - this.min + 1) + this.min);
    } },
  render() {
    return this.$scopedSlots.default({
      random: this.random
    });

  } 
});
let app = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    trigger:0
  },
  methods:{
    randFun:function(){
      this.trigger = this.trigger+1;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:'Roboto';
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3,1fr);
}

li{
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  align-items:center;
  justify-items:center;
}
li:hover{
  background:#eee;
}

.highlight{
  background:#7ed6df;
  color:#130f40;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <random v-slot="{random}" :trigger="trigger" max="9" min="1" >
  <grid v-bind:randval="random"></grid>
   </random>
  <button v-on:click="randFun">CLICK</button>
</div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="grid">
  <ul> 
    <li v-for="item, i in items" v-bind:id='"cell_"+i' v-bind:ref='"cell_"+i' class="cells" :class="{ highlight: (i === randval) }">
      <span>{{item}}</span><span>{{i}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</script>
```